# API access to instagram notification feed

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

Currently I'm building a social media light, which blinks when there's an update on your Facebook/Twitter/Instagram/.... Now I'm looking at Instagram and I wish to know when someone liked one of my posts. [The official API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) doesn't have this functionality. I then found that there was an unofficial version which implements more functionality of the official app. [This is a version for PHP](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API).

After looking for a while I couldn't find the API endpoint for accessing the likes feed. I think it's possible, since you can even request it in the web interface. Before I start on scraping it myself, are there other ways?

I also took a look at services like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), but the functionality isn't there either.

Currently I'm writing the app for Python, but I'm getting incredibly frustrated with the limited functionality the various social media offer. Facebook removed its notification functionality, Instagram doesn't have one and I haven't started on Twitter yet, but I get a feeling it will be a headache as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram shutdown its Feed API a litte over a year ago that provided this functionality that IFTTT and others used.

[Instagram Platform Update](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update)